# Grails application running on Tomcat6 - Context initialization failed

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy

I have developed an application in Grails (1.3.7) and I am running it on Tomcat6, which is running on Ubuntu Server.

This error is reported after deploy of the application. Do  you have idea what might be wrong?

```
2011-12-18 00:06:41,319 [main] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: static for class: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:70)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: static for class: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DomainClassGrailsPlugin.registerConstraintsProperty(DomainClassGrailsPlugin.groovy:169)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClassProperty$ComponentDomainClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsDomainClassProperty.java:543)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClassProperty.setEmbedded(DefaultGrailsDomainClassProperty.java:484)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass.establishDomainClassRelationship(DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java:481)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass.establishRelationships(DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java:252)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java:119)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DomainClassArtefactHandler.newArtefactClass(DomainClassArtefactHandler.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.AnnotationDomainClassArtefactHandler.newArtefactClass(AnnotationDomainClassArtefactHandler.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:640)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.configureLoadedClasses(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:347)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.initialise(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:857)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.java:110)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is still an issue for you, but I assume that this is a re-deploy of a grails application? Where the context loading actually fails is random (it happened to me on a localization class).

According to the accepted answer here: [How to debug ContextLoader - Context initialization failed and BeanCreationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834733/how-to-debug-contextloader-context-initialization-failed-and-beancreationexcep)

... something is theoretically wrong wrong or misconfigured with your tomcat cache.

Remove the files in your tomcat6 /work and /tmp directories and try to re-deploy. The tomcat6 `$CATALINA_HOME/work` directory on my ubuntu machine is actually `/var/cache/tomcat6`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says "No such property: static for class: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl" which implies you have some code like

```
Foo.metaClass.static.someNewMethod = { ... }
```

which is adding a static metamethod to the `Foo` class. If you're using an older version of Groovy you need to quote the `static` part:

```
Foo.metaClass.'static'.someNewMethod = { ... }
```

Comment: I am really sure that I have not implemented that kind of method. Can this be an error in Grails?