# @XmlElementRef issue: Invalid XmlElementRef on property {property}, Referenced element not declared

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

When I try to debug in SpringToolSuite. It sometimes fired an exception

```
Invalid XmlElementRef on property expression on class org.opengeoportal.ogc.wmc.jaxb.UpperBoundaryType. Referenced Element not declared.
```

exception.
But interestingly, other times the debug works well. I've looked around online and some people suggest it could be library conflicts. Is that possible? If yes, how should I track down the problem?

The error message:

```
2014-11-05 14:48:31 Jaxb2Marshaller [INFO] Creating JAXBContext with classes to be bound [class org.opengeoportal.ogc.wmc.jaxb.ViewContextType]
2014-11-05 14:48:31 ThreadPoolTaskExecutor [INFO] Shutting down ExecutorService
2014-11-05 14:48:31 ContextLoader [ERROR] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'marshaller': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Exception Description: Invalid XmlElementRef on property expression on class org.opengeoportal.ogc.wmc.jaxb.UpperBoundaryType. Referenced Element not declared.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50006] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: Invalid XmlElementRef on property expression on class org.opengeoportal.ogc.wmc.jaxb.UpperBoundaryType. Referenced Element not declared.]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My @XmlElementRef in UpperBoundaryType.java
public class UpperBoundaryType {

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "expression", namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/ogc", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<?> expression;

/**
 * Gets the value of the expression property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link PropertyNameType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LiteralType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BinaryOperatorType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BinaryOperatorType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BinaryOperatorType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ExpressionType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BinaryOperatorType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link FunctionType }{@code >}
 *     
 */
public JAXBElement<?> getExpression() {
    return expression;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the expression property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link PropertyNameType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LiteralType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BinaryOperatorType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BinaryOperatorType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BinaryOperatorType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ExpressionType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BinaryOperatorType }{@code >}
 *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link FunctionType }{@code >}
 *     
 */
public void setExpression(JAXBElement<?> value) {
    this.expression = ((JAXBElement<?> ) value);
}}
```

My ObjectFactory file defines the expression

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/ogc", name = "expression")
public JAXBElement<ExpressionType> createExpression(ExpressionType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<ExpressionType>(_Expression_QNAME, ExpressionType.class, null, value);
}
```

in a class annotated by @XmlRegistry

**Environment:** 
STS 3.6.2
JavaSE 1.7

Original answers:
Found out instantaneously after I entered my question! It's probably due to the incompatible JDK version: the @XMLElementRef file is created using vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6 but my project's Java Compiler is 7. Changed the complier to 6 and it works!

I used to thought I found the solution: incompatible JDK version. But it's actually not... The build get passed through several times after I change JDK to 1.6 but after that the debug failed still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution!

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834733/how-to-debug-contextloader-context-initialization-failed-and-beancreationexcep): Deleting the work/ and temp/ directory in your Java Servlet does the trick. But I still don't understand why.... Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: 
The above solution might be just a temporary one. The error is actually a syntax error in my bean definition file that I used to ignored... After fixing that, everything is right!

**Update 05/07/2015**

This turned out to be a IDE dependent issue. This issue only happens in Eclipse/SST. When I used IntelliJ (full version), this issue is gone.

Allen

Answer (score 0):

For me the error occcured because of an abstract type. So I had a Condition XmlElement and Condition was abstract and I had to add to the parent class something like @XmlSeeAlso({ LevelCondition.class, SomeOtherCondition.class, ... }), so that it knows all the concrete types.